MongoDB run loop to add incremental index value in low size array
I have a MongoDB collection where I have an array of objects (low size) and I want to add an incremental index value to each element of the array of objects.
Like index starts from 0 to array length - 1.
Data :
  db="abc" : {
    "array": [
      {
        "_id": "a",
        "timestamp": "t1",
        "type": "object"
      }
     ]
   }


db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$array"
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "array.index": {
                "$add": [
                    {
                        "$ifNull": ["$index", 0]
                    },
                    1
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "array": {
                "$push": "$$ROOT.array"
            }
        }
    }
])


MongoDB playground link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/SWw7rIYHNcj
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$array",
      "includeArrayIndex": "index"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "array.index": {
        "$toInt": "$index"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "array": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT.array"
      }
    }
  }
])


$unwind stage:
Opens an array field ($array) from the input documents.
Creates a new document for each element in the array.
Includes the array index of each element in a new field using includeArrayIndex.
$addFields stage:
Adds a new field ("array.index") to each document.
Converts the "index" field to an integer using the $toInt operator..
$group stage:
Groups documents based on the "_id" field.
Creates an "array" field within each group using the $push operator.

Here's another way to do it.  Comments are in the pipeline.
db.collection.aggregate([
  { // just add index if type is array
    "$match": {
      "array": {"$type": "array"}
    }
  },
  { // map each element with incremental index
    "$set": {
      "array": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            // produce index values
            "$range": [0, {"$size": "$array"}]
          },
          "as": "idx",
          "in": {
            // merge index into each object
            "$mergeObjects": [
              {"index": "$$idx"},
              {"$arrayElemAt": ["$array", "$$idx"]}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Try it on mongoplayground.net.

You don't need to $unwind the array. The $unwind can be slow on performance if you have a large number of elements in the array. Similarly, $group can also be slow on performance by having to wind the unwound documents back together again.
For better performance, you can just $map over the array and use $indexOfArray to get the current index from the parent array. By adding an an object with an index field you can merge that with the original object in each iteration of the $map like so:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "abc.array": {
        $map: {
          input: "$abc.array",
          as: "element",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$element",
              {
                index: {
                  $indexOfArray: [
                    "$abc.array",
                    "$$element"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

See HERE for a working example using an extrapolated set of documents from your sample document.
